# noHistory and child activity result

Tags: android

I have the following case:

**Activity A** -> **Activity B** (noHistory set) -> **Activity C**

I need to have a result from **C** returned to **A** when C finishes. Is it possible?

The only way I could achieve this is by retaining the history for B and forwarding the result from C via it. Thus, though, if B is launched and the program is restored from background, B will be displayed. I would prefer that B is not kept on the stack.

Comment: why not starting A from C when you want to pass data to it? launchmode singleinstance could be your solution for that case...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT should do the trick.

Comment: @Zelimir - that did it. C acted as a sub-screen of B (preferences) and A was the main activity that needed to refresh according to C's result.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Should I add it as an answer so we close that story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already confirmed by Kamen, FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT should be used in such a case. As tutorial says:

*`If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transfered to the new activity. This way the new activity can call setResult(int) and have that result sent back to the reply target of the original activity.`*

Answer (score 5):

**Additional details**

[image]

**In activity A:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

**In activity A:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      // TODO
   }
}
```

**In activity B:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(intent);
```

**In activity C:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// put something to intent
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```